# Shell script rename

Tags: shell-script

Implement a command, that is the content of a variable.

I am trying to create a bash rename program that can rename all the files in a given directory. I have the following program:

```
for PATHFILE in tracks/*
do
   path="$(dirname "$PATHFILE")"
   file="$(basename "$PATHFILE")"

   program='mv';

   if [[ "$file" =~ ([0-9]*)\s*(.*) ]]
   then

       from=${path}/${file}
       to=${path}/${BASH_REMATCH[1]};

       command_string="$program '$from' '$to'";

       #here the command_string contains the command i want to execute.
       $(command_string);
       #causes error:
       # mv: target ''\''tracks/01'\''' is not a directory.

       break;
    fi

done
```

If I run the command directly myself then it runs without a problem.
I also dont quite get why the system is adding those commas around the string.

If I echo the variable to the screen then i can just copy it, run and it runs without error. but if i try to run it in-code then i keep getting this error.

How do I get this to work?

Comment: which shell? bash?

Comment: Your issue with single quotes should be at the line `command_string="$program '$from' '$to'";`

Comment: You may find the discussion here helpful: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: what's the purpose of ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ?

Comment: @lese It's the value captured by the first parenthesis in the regular expression.

Comment: yebb.. the bash shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `$(command_string)` would give you the error "bash: command_string: command not found" as its a command substitution. A command substitution would run the command within the parenthesis and substitute the whole thing with that command's output.

Secondly, even if you had used just `$command_string` to execute your command, you still add single quotes to the filenames.  The filenames don't have single quotes in them.

In general, just avoid putting commands into variables.  See "[How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946)".

Instead, maybe something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for pathname in tracks/*; do
    if [[ "$pathname" =~ ([0-9]+)[[:blank:]]* ]]; then
        newpathname="${pathname%/*}/${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        printf 'Would move "%s" to "%s"\n' "$pathname" "$newpathname"
        # mv -i "$pathname" "$newpathname"
        break
    fi
done
```

This loop does (I think) what you're trying to do.  I've commented out the bit that actually renames the file for safety.